# How to specify relative path in Robot Framework using Selenium

Tags: robotframework

I'm having a text file in Resource folder and my robot script in sibling folder namely Test, I need to use the relative path otherwise I need to specify the path explicitly once I changed the project location.

```
TEST PROJECT (Root folder)
|
|_____ Resource (folder)
|       |_____ MyProfile.txt
|       |_____ MyPicture.jpg
|
|_____ Test (folder)
        |_____ MyTest.robot
```

I want to access the `MyProfile.txt` in `MyTest.robot` using relative reference instead of absolute path.

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can give the Relative path by using the following approach

```
${CURDIR}${/}..\\Resource\\MyProfile.txt
```

The `${CURDIR}` will return the path of where you are using this code, then we need to back track using the navigation operator `..\\`

But if you use `${EXECDIR}` will return the path of the file is executing.

```
${EXECDIR}${/}..\\Resource\\MyProfile.txt
```

Here the code and execution both are handled in a single file, so both the code will give you the appropriate location of `MyProfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

or another way, you may add the project root folder to the sys.path. it will search up the referenced resources from the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that

**../../Resources/MyProfile.txt**